# Proportion of irreducible fractions in $\frac{1}{n}, \frac{2}{n}, ... ,\frac{n}{n}$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

How small can the proportion of irreducible fractions be if $1 < n < 10^6$?

Comment: as small as $\frac{1}{10^6-1}$

Comment: If n is prime then only n/n is reducible.  Find n = the largest prime less than $10^6 - 1$ and that will have the smallest proportion; 1/n.

Comment: @fleablood: No, it will have the largest proportion, $(n-1)/n$.

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/58750/how-many-irreducible-fractions-between-0-and-1-have-denominator-less-than-n.

Comment: @TonyK that's what I get for being online at three in the morning...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A fraction $\dfrac ab$ is irreducible if $\gcd (a,b)=1$. Thus $\dfrac rn; r\in\{1,2,...,n-1\}$ will be irreducible iff $\gcd (r,n)=1$. This leaves only $\phi(n)$ possibilities for $r$, where $\phi (n)$ is the [Euler's totient function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler's_totient_function) of $n$.

Thus the proportion of such irreducible fractions is therefore $\dfrac{\phi(n)}{n-1}$, considering fractions till $\dfrac {n-1}n$, as $\dfrac nn$ is always reducible.

Answer (score 3):

The proportion of irreducible fractions is
$$
\dfrac{\phi(n)}{n} = \prod_{p\mid n} \left(1-\frac{1}{p}\right)
$$

So the smallest proportion is attained when $n$ is the product of all possible primes such that $n<10^6$, that is, $n$ is the largest [primorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primorial) less than $10^6$.

This explains Michael's answer.

Comment: That makes sense, thank you for the explanation!

Answer (score 1):

$2*3*5*7*11*13*17=510510$.
The proportion of irreducible fractions is $$\frac12\frac23\frac45\frac67\frac{10}{11}\frac{12}{13}\frac{16}{17}=\frac{92160}{510510}\approx 0.18$$