# Is there a Hamiltonian cycle of $m$ x $n$ rectangular lattice points (these are the vertices) in $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that no two edges are parallel?

Tags: graph-theory, induction, examples-counterexamples, pigeonhole-principle, hamiltonian-path

Let $m,n\geq 2$ and consider the rectangular lattice of $mn$ vertices in $\mathbb{R}^2,\ (i,j);\ i\in \{1,2,\ldots,m\},\ j\in \{1,2,\ldots,n\}.\ $ Call these vertices $X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_{mn}.$ Is there a Hamiltonian cycle of these $mn$ points i.e. vertices such that no two lines (i.e. edges) are parallel? [Edges are allowed to intersect each other and edges are allowed to pass through vertices.] I have tried to find an example for small values of $m$ and $n$ but to no avail. Maybe the answer is no, at least in part due to pigeonhole principle and some induction argument. Alternatively, maybe there are examples for large enough $m,n.$

Comment: By “counter-example”, you seem to mean an example of such a cycle? (You didn’t make any claim that this would be a counter-example to.)

Comment: I don't understand. You have told us what the vertices of your graph are, but you didn't say what the edges are. Are you talking about the *complete* graph on those $mn$ vertices?

Comment: @user14111: As I understand the question, the edges are just line segments connecting any two of the vertices; there’s no requirement that they be horizontal or vertical.

Comment: Joriki is correct in his second comment. Edges don't have to be horizontal or vertical. They can join any two vertices together. And I meant "find an example" not counter-example. You are right. I will leave the tag "counter-example", as  an "example" in my question can be thought of as a counter-example if we frame the question as a negative proposition: "Proposition: there does not exists such a Hamiltonian cycle such that blah blah blah...", if that makes sense.

Comment: The [length of the Farey sequence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/58750) of irreducible fractions between $0$ and $1$ with denominator at most $n$ only grows as $\frac3{\pi^2}n^2$. You have twice as many directions (positive and negative fractions), but that’s still only $\sim\frac6{\pi^2}n^2\lt n^2$. So this will generally not be possible on a square lattice. I’ll write some code to check which rectangles have enough different directions.

Comment: @joriki I have not heard of those sequences before. Interesting.

Comment: Sorry, that was wrong. You actually have four times as many directions, positive and negative fractions and their reciprocals. So that makes $\sim\frac{12}{\pi^2}n^2\gt n^2$ directions, so there could be such cycles even in square lattices.

Comment: It turns out that rectangles and small squares have fewer directions than this asymptotic value, sometimes fewer than required and often barely enough. So it’s not surprising you didn’t find an example for small values of $m$ and $n$; there’s a bit more leeway in larger squares.

Comment: I found some examples; will be posting an answer shortly.

Comment: @joriki I look forward to them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, the length of the $n$-th [Farey sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Farey_sequence), that is, the number of irreducible fractions between $0$ and $1$ with denominators up to $n$, is asymptotic to $\frac3{\pi^2}n^2$. Since the differences in an $n\times n$ lattice go up to $n-1$, their possible ratios are given by the $(n-1)$-th Farey sequence and its additive and multiplicative inverses. Thus, asymptotically a square $n\times n$ lattice has $\frac{12}{\pi^2}n^2\approx1.2n^2$ different directions, enough for each of the $n^2$ edges to use a different one.

[Here’s Java code](https://github.com/joriki/math/blob/master/info/joriki/math/stackexchange/Question4861188.java) that performs an exhaustive search for all solutions. Here’s the number of solutions for all lattices with at most $27$ vertices:

\begin{array}{c|ccc}
m\setminus n&3&4&5&6&7&8&9\\\hline
3&❌&16&❌&1800&❌&365128&❌\\
4&&1880&56120&34669920\\
5&&&❌
\end{array}

There are no solutions for any of the $2\times n$ lattices (even though they have just enough directions). An ❌ indicates that the lattice has fewer directions than vertices, so there can’t be a solution. Of the remaining lattices, the only one with more directions than vertices is $4\times 6$, which has $26$ directions. This is reflected in the solution count being two orders of magnitude greater than the one for the $3\times8$ lattice, which has the same number of vertices. The enumeration for the $4\times7$ lattice is still running and will take another day or so.

The counts don’t account for symmetry, so for rectangles they include $4$ equivalent copies of each solution, $8$ for the square. These numbers (with or without symmetry reduction) aren’t in OEIS.

Here’s one solution for each of the lattices:

[image: 3x4 lattice]
       
[image: 3x6 lattice]
       
[image: 3x8 lattice]

[image: 4x4 lattice]
       
[image: 4x7 lattice]

[image: 4x6 lattice]
       
[image: 4x5 lattice]